# devexpress React Grid table colspan

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devexpress

I am using dex devexpress React Grid。
I want to merge cells in the first row while keeping the other rows unchanged.

```
const Cell = props => {
  const { tableColumn } = props;
  if (tableColumn.column.name === "name") {
    return <Table.Cell {...props} colSpan={4} />;
  }
  return null;
};
```

```
 render() {
    const { rows, columns } = this.state;

    return (
      <Grid rows={rows} columns={columns}>
        <Table cellComponent={Cell} />
        <TableHeaderRow />
      </Grid>
    );
  }
```

This is demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/devextreme-react-grid-for-bootstrap-4-l8w39

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify just the first row you need to check the `tableRow` property like the below:

```
const Cell = (props) => {
  const { column, tableRow, value } = props;
  console.log(props);
  if (tableRow.rowId === 0) {
    if (column.name === "name") {
      return (
        <Table.Cell {...props} colSpan={4}>
          <div
            style={{
              textAlign: "center",
              border: "1px solid red",
              width: "100%"
            }}
          >
            {value}
          </div>
        </Table.Cell>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  return <Table.Cell {...props} />;
};
```

[The sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/devextreme-react-grid-for-bootstrap-4-forked-pxmxs4)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it has been very helpful to me. Now there is another question, if the names are the same and the cities are the same, they all need to merge. How do you write the code?

Comment: @Lynn  Well, that needs to be another question according to SO rules, but before asking a new question what needs to be merged the rows or the columns? If you want to merge rows it might not be possible at the component level but you can group the data instead.